# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference PDO

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo, sql-like

I am trying a query with LIKE in PDO however I get the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference PDO, in this part of the code. How could I solve it?

```
function buscador($DB,$categoria_id,$buscado){
    $productos = NULL;
    $sql = "SELECT * from producto WHERE categoria_id = ? LIKE ?";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    //$params = [$categoria_id,':keywords', '%' . $buscado . '%'];
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$categoria_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,':keywords', '%' . $buscado . '%',PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $productos = $stmt->fetchAll();

    return $productos;
}
```

Comment: Just to say, you are missing the column that you want to do the LIKE operation on in `WHERE categoria_id = ? LIKE ?`

Comment: Here you're not passing parameters properly: `$stmt->bindParam(2,':keywords', '%' . $buscado . '%',PDO::PARAM_STR);` (note how you have 4 of them, unlike the 3 in the first bind). Also your query seems incorrect. Which column is supposed to use `LIKE`?

Comment: The column that should use like is $ searched @El_Vanja

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * from producto WHERE categoria_id = ? AND SOMECOLUMN LIKE ?";`

Comment: Oh yes thanks if I change this function give me the same error yet @RiggsFolly

Comment: Now change the bindParam

Comment: How? I thought about removing the part that says :keywords and putting only this `'%' . $buscado . '%'` but I still have the same error, what am I doing wrong? @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `bindParam` is passed by reference and therefore cannot be a  literal it must be be a variable.

You also have an error in the Query syntax which I fixed, although I dont know the column name to use, please change that before attempting to use this code.

```
function buscador($DB,$categoria_id,$buscado){
    $productos = NULL;
    $sql = "SELECT * from producto WHERE categoria_id = ? AND othercol LIKE ?";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

    $p2 = '%' . $buscado . '%';

    $stmt->bindParam(1,$categoria_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$p2,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $productos = $stmt->fetchAll();

    return $productos;
}
```